# How do I recognize invalid dates in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When modifying Active Record object's attributes (like `Task.update date: '2015-01-01'`), I'd like to know when the value is invalid (`'2015-01-32'` or `'whatever'`). Right now, `activerecord` just writes `nil` in case of those, not very friendly I must say. Previous value is lost. I'd like to leave it there, if user inputted nothing like date.

Is there any more sensible way to figure it out than the following?

```
if ActiveRecord::Attribute.from_user('date', '2015-01-32', ActiveRecord::Type::Date.new).value
  puts 'valid date'
end
```

P.S. Just in case [someone](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute.rb#L37) [wants](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute.rb#L42) to [know](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute.rb#L110) [how](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/value.rb#L34) [type casting](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/value.rb#L93) [happens](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/date.rb#L21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no way to tell `activerecord` to not discard values, and no public interface for checking if a date is valid, than the best option must be to use [validation](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_date :date
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to parse it and when it raise error then its nit valid:

```
valid = Date.parse('2015-01-30').present? rescue false  # true

valid = Date.parse('2015-01-32').present? rescue false  # false
```

Comment: Ideally, if `activerecord` has a notion of invalid date, it must be publicly available. Otherwise, an app and `activerecord` might not always agree on what is invalid date. Which would lead to likely incorrect behavior.

Comment: you mean you want to check with the same way activerecord check before insert in database ? so ideally they have a way

Comment: Sort of. I want to know if the value is going to be accepted, or discarded. Which means yes, I want to check if the date is valid the way `activerecord` does. And that's what I do in the question. How does it look to you? Additionally, there are other options. If `activerecord` can be told to not discard values. Or the one I'm going to use in my answer.